# how to use batch field name in Kofax Transformation Script

Tags: vbscript, field, capture, kofax

I have created a batch field in Kofax capture as " Invoice_from _Email"

which i need to call in KTM script to assing its value as true.

how can i call the batch field value in KTM script.?

Comment: Hi Setphen with regards to the above query i need to call the batch field because i have a scenario in which i have added to script for no rotation  for scanned images coming in the validation. Below is the script for the same for no rotation.

Comment: Dim i As Long
     
     
   

         'If pXDoc.ExtractionClass = "Invoice" Then
         ' change orientation for all pages from unknown to NoRotation
         ' this will prevent the OCR from doing orientation detection

            For i =  0 To pXDoc.CDoc.Pages.Count - 1
            pXDoc.CDoc.Pages(i).Rotation = Csc_RT_NoRotation

         Next i

         End If

End Sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different options on how to do this.

**Mapping a batch/root folder field:**
The first would be to map the field.  In Project Builder open Project Settings and check "Enable folders" on the General tab.  This maps the KC batch to the KTM root folder and does not require you to actually create any additional folders. Then you can create a field, presumably named "Invoice_from_Email",on the root folder which you will be able to map to a KC field in the Synchronization Tool for the batch class.

Because the field is mapped, you have read/write access.

To use from script it would be:

```
pXRootFolder.Fields.ItemByName("Invoice_from_Email").Text
```

**Read-only access without mapping**

```
pXRootFolder.XValues.ItemByName("AC_FIELD_" & BatchFieldName)
```

From the documentation:

> Note   If you cannot access the field values via script, then you need
>   to check whether the “Populate all index fields for read-only access
>   in script” option is selected on the Extended Synchronization Settings
>   window of the Kofax Transformation Modules - Synchronization Tool.
>   This option is cleared by default, and available only if Kofax Capture
>   10.0.2 (service pack 2) or a newer version is installed.

If you don't see this setting it means you have an version prior to when it was added and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Setphen. I will try the same and get back to you.